# Ubuntu gives different visuals in window switcher

Tags: 16.04, unity

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoNoI.png)

How to revert this to normal effects?

Comment: Have you modified any configuration files? Is this fresh install?

Comment: Freshly installed... The normal switcher is actually working fine(you can see it in the background)but there is some overlay

Comment: I just found the solution. Checking static application switcher and disabling application switcher in CompizConfig settings manager did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install CompizConfigue Settings Manager.
2. In categories, select Window Management.
3. Check Static application switcher and Uncheck Application switcher